# How to use withCredentials to pass cookie to server?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, cookies, xmlhttprequest

After the user signed in successfully by submitting the sign in form, the server will store user's credentials in cookie.

I need to be able to send a XMLHttpRequest to access a protected route on the same server, same domain.

Here is my implementation:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost/protected_method', true);
            xhr.withCredentials = true;
            xhr.send(null);
            xhr.onload = function(aData) {
                    // I get the page of asking to signin
                    // which means that the cookie was not passed?
                    console.log(aData.currentTarget.response);
            }
```

What I expect is that the server will accept the request as an authenticated user, however the result is the html page that asks user to sign in.

How to do the post request and get recognized by the server?

Comment: [`XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) has no effect on **same-domain** requests. Just set cookies in usual way (by `document.cookie`). However storing user's credentials in cookies is very bad idea.

Comment: +1 to what @hindmost said. If you are unsure about what you should save into cookies and what not: Think about cookies like URL parameters. Would you show the password in the URL? No, so you shouldn't save it in cookies either.

Comment: the cookie I want to send within the request is the the cookie I've got from the server after successful authentication, its encrypted and it just has a key that is related to the user session on the server.

The cookie is already in the document, but it seems that its not sent as the server has rejected the request by redirecting to the page of entering credentials. How would I pass the cookie within the request? shouldn't it be passed without any action from me?